# Addition law on moduli space of curves

Tags: algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves, plane-curves, algebraic-curves

Dislaimer: I know very little about this, so if parts of my question don't make sense, please feel free to edit in a way that does, or ask me to clarify.

Let $\mathcal{M}_{1,2}$ be the moduli space of genus 1 curves (plane curves with base field $\mathbb{C}$) with 2 marked points. I think there is a map (thought of as addition in a sense like addition on an elliptic curve) that is
\begin{align*}
\mathcal{M}_{1,2} \times \mathcal{M}_{1,2} &\to \mathcal{M}_{1,1} \\
(C,p_1,p_2), (C,p_1,p_3) &\mapsto (C,p_2+p_3 - p_1)
\end{align*}
where $p_1$ is sort of an identity element. My question is: is this correct? If so, how should I think about it, and where can I read more about it?

Comment: How would you add $(C,p_1,p_2)$ to $(C',p'_1,p'_2)$ where $C$ and $C'$ are nonisomorphic curves?

Comment: I don't know but I think I only care about the case when $C= C'$, so assume we're just looking at this subset. In particular, the only curves I am looking at are smooth.

Comment: Well, there is a map $\mathcal{M}_{1,2} \times \mathcal{M}_{1,2}\to \overline{\mathcal{M}}_{1,2}$  where you map into a compactification of the moduli space and the map just glues the two curves at a marked point...

Comment: The compactification is for smooth curves. If your $\mathcal{M}$ already includes singular curves then you probably don't need that, but I'm not so familiar with that case.